# fur in falling softbody simulation not coming with the object

Tags: soft-body

I am making a simple softbody simulation in which the object has fur. but when i play the animation the fur of the object stays in the same place while the object falls:[image: fur not falling]

this is my first time using the fur effect do please tell how to solve this

Here is my blend file:
[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: ok. i have edited the post to have the blend file.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your modifiers.

First soft body.

like this:

[image]

UPDATE: answer to your 2nd question:
yes you can, check hair dynamics

[image]

Comment: this was really helpful. thanks:)

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: is there also  a way to make the hair particles collide with the stairs...right now they are going through it. you can answer it here:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215803/fur-of-cube-going-through-mesh

Comment: i updated my answer -> check hair dynamics

Comment: alright, thanks:)