# fur of cube going through mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, hair, soft-body

I am making a simple fur softbody simulation, in which the object falls to a stair in a satisfying manner. When i play this, the fur(generated through particles) seems to go through the mesh of the stairs.
is there a way to make the hair particles collide with the mesh?[image: fur intersecting with mesh]

when i enable hair dynamics the cube intersects with the stairs. like this:
[image: Cube intersecting with stair]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hair particles do respond to the Collision physics option. However, if you have Collision on the cube already to keep hair from going through it, it’s margin may cause the hair to stick straight out despite the stairs.

As a sidenote, Rigid Body and Collision can coexist.

Comment: I have added collision on the stairs, but the particles still seem to go through the stairs

Comment: Double check the normal’s. Are they pointing the right way?

Comment: yes, the face orientation are all in the right directions

Comment: You have disabled hair dynamics. The hair will not physically respond if this is off.

Comment: i enabled hair dynamics, but now it gives even more issues with the cube

Comment: i enabled hair dynamics. this seems to  make the cube intersect with the stairs. i have edited the post to show this please check

Comment: Yep. Physics at this size either needs a lot of solver steps and tight collision margins, or you need to fake something.

Comment: but why would the cube intersect the stairs now?

Comment: Umm, that is weird.